# Manually set combo interface for RJ45 Cisco 3560-CG Series

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-ios, cisco-catalyst, interface

I have a Cisco Catalyst 3560-CG that has two combo ports with SFP and RJ45 each. Is it possible to manually set the combo port to use the RJ45 only? If so, how is it done? I am troubleshooting a connection and I don't want this to be a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the `media-type` interface command:

```
interface <slot/port>
 media-type rj45
!
```

-or-

```
interface <slot/port>
 media-type sfp
!
```

Comment: That's it, thanks! It turns out my copper port may have dirty or bad pins.

Answer (score 2):

The 3560 uses the physical port that can get a link and deactivates the other as long as the link is up. When both variants can get a link (at power on) the SFP port is prioritized.

You can disable the SFP priority with the `interface media-type` command.